# JPanel not auto resizing with GroupLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, windowbuilder, grouplayout

I'm using Window Builder with palette to add `GroupLayout` to a `JPanel` that is using a `JScrollPane` for auto resize, and for some reason it didn't work only in this case. What did I do wrong?

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(null);

JScrollPane BestAntscrollPane = new JScrollPane();
BestAntscrollPane.setBounds(12, 91, 1647, 1500);
panel.add(BestAntscrollPane);       
JPanel BestAntPanel = new JPanel();
BestAntscrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(BestAntPanel);
BestAntPanel.setLayout(null);
BestAntscrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
BestAntPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(512,2500));
GroupLayout gl_BestAntPanel = new GroupLayout(BestAntPanel);
gl_BestAntPanel.setHorizontalGroup(
    gl_BestAntPanel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 1624, Short.MAX_VALUE)
);
gl_BestAntPanel.setVerticalGroup(
    gl_BestAntPanel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGap(0, 2500, Short.MAX_VALUE)
);
BestAntPanel.setLayout(gl_BestAntPanel);
BestAntPanel.setVisible(false);
```

Comment: *"What did I do wrong?"* This `panel.setLayout(null);`. Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: **General tips:** 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 3) See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.) ..

Comment: .. 4) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently.